# Does org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer implements SinkFunction<T> sinkFunction

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to implement a simple flink job that use `org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors`, take a Kafka topic as input source and output to a Kafka sink. I am following this guide https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/connectors/datastream/kafka/ and write code as such

```
FlinkKafkaConsumer<String> kafkaConsumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>(TOPIC_IN, new SimpleStringSchema(), props);  //FlinkKafkaConsumer<String> testKafkaConsumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>(TOPIC_TEST, new SimpleStringSchema(), props);
        kafkaConsumer.setStartFromEarliest();
        DataStream<String> dataStream = env.addSource(kafkaConsumer);

        StringSchema stringSchema = new StringSchema(TOPIC_OUT);
        FlinkKafkaProducer<String> kafkaProducer = new FlinkKafkaProducer<>(TOPIC_OUT, stringSchema, props, FlinkKafkaProducer.Semantic.EXACTLY_ONCE);

        //addSink((SinkFunction<String>) kafkaProducer);

        dataStream.addSink(kafkaProducer);
```

However, `addSink`needs `SinkFunction` while I provide a `FlinkKafkaProducer`, which extends `TwoPhaseCommitSinkFunction`. I am confused why it complains and not works.
[image]

My pom.xml file is as follows

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-base</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-streaming-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: You are mixing artifacts from Flink 1.13.0 with 1.13.2. This is probably not the cause of the issue, but should be avoided nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

seems this class has been deprecated https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/kafka/package-summary.html.

Comment: FlinkKafkaProducer is deprecated in master, but not in 1.13.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `FlinkKafkaProducer` constructor with the method signature you're using. You could use this one:

```java
public FlinkKafkaProducer(
            String topicId,
            SerializationSchema<IN> serializationSchema,
            Properties producerConfig,
            @Nullable FlinkKafkaPartitioner<IN> customPartitioner,
            FlinkKafkaProducer.Semantic semantic,
            int kafkaProducersPoolSize)
```